# resize image in the views and load it in the templates in django

Tags: django, django-views

Is there any possible way to resize the original image in the views.py and then load the resized image from the views to the template? I tried using sorl-thumbnail and easy_thumbnail, they works great, but I don't know why, somehow whenever I upload it using the apache server, the server only loads the images uploaded by the django's inbuilt server, and when I load the page again with the django's inbuilt server it loads the uploaded image nicely. So, is there anyway that I can resize the image in the views itself, and then load it in the templates? And if there is, please kindly guide me how do I do it. Thank you!

models.py

```
class Status(models.Model):
    status = models.TextField()
    image = ImageField(upload_to=get_upload_file_name, blank=True)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now)
    creator = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name="creator_set")
    likes = models.ManyToManyField(User, through="Like")

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-pub_date']
        verbose_name_plural = ('Status')

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.status
```

Comment: I don't quite understand your problem with generating thumbnails in the template. But have you looked into the documentation of easy thumbnails? There's also a section on how to create thumbnails in python code: http://easy-thumbnails.readthedocs.org/en/latest/usage/#python

Answer (score 1):

Me, too, I don't understand your problem with generating thumbnails in the template. But if you want to create them in the view (or anywhere else in the python code), that will be possible with sorl thumbnail. In the sorl thumbnail docs, there's the following [low level api example](http://sorl-thumbnail.readthedocs.org/en/latest/examples.html#low-level-api-examples):

```
from sorl.thumbnail import get_thumbnail
im = get_thumbnail(my_file, '100x100', crop='center', quality=99)
```